Does MS-Windows use undocumented API to find 256x256 icons?
What API does MS-Windows use to find and load 256x256px icons from resources in .exe and .dll files ?
I find that the documented Windows API cannot find and load 256x256px icons.  See the function below when nSize==256:
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct  _GRPICONDIRENTRY
{
    BYTE  bWidth;
    BYTE  bHeight;
    BYTE  bColorCount;
    BYTE  bReserved;
    WORD  wPlanes;
    WORD  wBitCount;
    DWORD dwBytesInRes;
    WORD  nId;
} GRPICONDIRENTRY, *PGRPICONDIRENTRY;

typedef struct  _GRPICONDIR
{
    WORD idReserved;
    WORD idType;
    WORD idCount;
    GRPICONDIRENTRY idEntries[1];
} GRPICONDIR, * PGRPICONDIR;
#pragma pack(pop)


HICON Dll2Icon(LPCTSTR szFileName, int nSize)
{
    HICON   hIcon = 0;
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryEx( szFileName, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE );       
    HRSRC hResIbIconDir = FindResource(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(42), RT_GROUP_ICON);
    HGLOBAL hResDatIconDir = LoadResource(hMod, hResIbIconDir);
    PGRPICONDIR pIconDir = static_cast<PGRPICONDIR>(LockResource(hResDatIconDir));

    PGRPICONDIRENTRY pEntry;

    for (pEntry = pIconDir->idEntries; pEntry < &(pIconDir->idEntries[pIconDir->idCount]); pEntry++)
    {
        if ( (pEntry->bWidth == nSize) && (pEntry->bHeight == nSize) )
        {
            HRSRC hResIbIcon = FindResource(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(pEntry->nId), RT_ICON);
            HGLOBAL hResDatIcon = LoadResource(hMod, hResIbIcon);
            PBYTE pIcon = static_cast<PBYTE>(LockResource(hResDatIcon));

            hIcon = CreateIconFromResourceEx(pIcon, pEntry->dwBytesInRes, TRUE, 0x00030000, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
            FreeResource(hResDatIcon);
            break;
        }
    }
    FreeResource(hResDatIconDir);
    FreeLibrary(hMod);
    return hIcon;
}

The reason the function listed above fails for 256x256px icon images but succeeds finding the 255x255px icons is the width of the fields GRPICONDIRENTRY.bWidth and GRPICONDIRENTRY.bHeight which are byte-sized and thus cannot hold the number 256.
What API does Windows use to find such icon resolution ?
According to this article, MS-Windows supports 256x256 pixel icons since Windows Vista and if you select the menu View->Extra large icons in the Windows Explorer than the 256x256 icon will be displayed without a problem for .dll and .exe files but not for the .ico files (verified on Windows 7).

Here you may find resource files with all the icons resolutions from 8x8px to 256x256px.

Since 0 isn't otherwise used it is interpreted to mean 256.

In other words: A 256x256 icon is encoded as if it were a 0x0 icon. You can fix Dll2Icon by adding this: nSize = nSize == 256 ? 0 : nSize;. This will now find icons including 256x256 icons.

The function CreateIconFromResourceEx() somehow knows the dimensions of the 256x256 image in this resource even when the GRPICONDIRENTRY.bWidth and GRPICONDIRENTRY.bHeight are clobbered in the resource directory.

There is no such thing as a 255x255 icon. Icons are always square, and their size is a power of 2. Valid sizes are 8x8, 16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256. If you have something that is not a size of a power of 2, it's not an ICON.

@KenWhite none if this is true. Icons don't need to be square and don't need to be powers of two in size.

@KenWhite: Icons do not have to have dimensions which are powers of 2.  Download the files referred to at the bottom of the OP's question and see for yourself what icon dimensions are chosen by the Windows Explorer to display icons in its various views.  Also, the Microsoft's article disagrees with your power of 2 claim, see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/app-icon-construction#icon-sizes-win32

"The function CreateIconFromResourceEx() somehow knows the dimensions of the 256x256 image in this resource even when the GRPICONDIRENTRY.bWidth and GRPICONDIRENTRY.bHeight are clobbered" - The values aren't "clobbered". They follow a very specific protocol. The byte value of 0 means 256 px (wide or high). It is not a surprise that CreateIconFromResourceEx() can find 256x256 pixel icon images. It is merely following the rules of the ICO file format that supports encoding a width and height of 256 pixels.

When I wrote "clobbered", I did not mean GRPICONDIRENTRY.bWidth == 0 and GRPICONDIRENTRY.bHeight == 0.  I can put any junk in there and it does not affect CreateIconFromResourceEx()

That sounds like CreateIconFromResourceEx() simply ignores the bWidth/bHeight values altogether. As I explained in my proposed answer, those values are redundant anyway.


What API does Windows use to find such icon resolution ?

I don't know. I'm confident that whichever API is being called knows how to interpret icon resources.

According to this article, MS-Windows supports 256x256 pixel icons since Windows Vista [...].

I didn't find any evidence to support this statement. Support for 256 pixels in either dimension was introduced in Windows 95. In his first installment of the evolution of the ICO file format (Monochrome beginnings), Raymond Chen explains:

The bWidth and bHeight are the dimensions of the image. Originally, the supported range was 1 through 255, but starting in Windows 95 (and Windows NT 4), the value 0 is accepted as representing a width or height of 256.

I don't know whether this is (or was) accurate. A more flexible evolution scheme would certainly have been for the value 0 to mean: "Ignore the value". Since there is redundancy anyway (RT_ICON resources start with a BITMAPINFOHEADER unless it is a PNG image) a resource reader could be implemented that ignores a value of 0 and pulls the dimension information from the RT_ICON resource.
Regardless of that, there doesn't need to be any undocumented, secret API to be used for 256x256px icon support. Since none of the APIs (neither directly nor indirectly) repeated the mistake of encoding the width and height as 8-bit values, all of them are immune to the ICO file format evolution that picked an unused value (0) to mean something else.
However, since you are using undocumented file/resource format internals, your code now has to know about those internals. Specifically, your Dll2Icon implementation needs to provide special handling of icon directory entries where the bWidth and/or bHeight members report a value of 0.
