Efficiently finding the 1st icon group in a DLL's resources
This article states that MS-Windows extracts the 1st icon embedded in .dll or .exe file for displaying it in the Windows Shell.

Which Icon?
If an .EXE or .DLL file has only one RT_GROUP_ICON resource, the first step is trivial; Windows simply uses that resource. However, if more than one such group resource exists in the file, Windows must decide which one to use. Windows NT simply chooses the first resource listed in the application's RC script.

Note that this refers to the 1st RT_GROUP_ICON resource, NOT to the smallest resource ID (or name)!
i.e. Not to the Resource ID == 0 or Resource ID == 1 nor Resource ID == "AAA", which might not even exist. Even if an .exe or .dll file has only one RT_GROUP_ICON resource, finding its identifier seems to be a non-trivial task.
I wrote the following functions in order to replicate the Shell's behavior:
BOOL EnumProc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpType, LPTSTR idResource, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    HRSRC hResIbIconDir = FindResource(hModule, idResource, RT_GROUP_ICON);
    *reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL*>(lParam) = LoadResource(hModule, hResIbIconDir);
    return FALSE;
}

HGLOBAL FindFirstIconInDLL(LPCTSTR szFileName)
{
    HGLOBAL res = 0;
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibraryEx(szFileName, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE);
    EnumResourceNames(hMod, RT_GROUP_ICON, EnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&res));
    return res;
}

The code above finds and loads the 1stRT_GROUP_ICON resource but is pretty inefficient and ugly because:

It requires forming two separate functions.
The EnumResourceNames() is needed to retrieve the Resource Identifier for the 2nd parameter of the FindResource() function.
EnumResourceNames() requires a separate callback procedure EnumProc().
FindResource() finds the first resource by its identifier again - despite it having been located by EnumResourceNames() already.

Is there a simpler or more efficient method of finding the 1st RT_GROUP_ICON resource in a .dll or .exe file?

The built-in ExtractIconEx() function is simpler, pass 0 for the index.

The ExtractIconEx() is useless for finding the 1st RT_GROUP_ICON resource. Without an access to this resource, it is impossible to load an arbitrary RT_ICON resource and consequently icons of dimensions other than SM_CXICON, SM_CYICON, SM_CXSMICON, and SM_CYSMICON. See the following question for the details of loading an icon of arbitrary dimensions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79057380/does-ms-windows-use-undocumented-api-to-find-256x256-icons

If you want to reproduce what the Shell does, you want to use some Shell API (there are many relative to icon & thumbnails, and here you're using the low level resource API). What exactly are you trying to do in the first place?

I mean what Shell behavior are you trying to replicate? The Shell uses modern (Vista+) functions like this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitemimagefactory-getimage which is perfectly capable of returning everything you see visually.

@SimonMourier: I am yet to find a Shell API that would allow me to choose the 1st RT_GROUP_ICON resource in a .dll file and later to select and load an arbitrary RT_ICON resource that is listed in it.  See the Dll2Icon() function in the related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79057380/does-ms-windows-use-undocumented-api-to-find-256x256-icons

@SimonMourier:   In this question I am only asking about an efficient method to find and load the 1st RT_GROUP_ICON resource from a .dll file (just like the Shell does).  The function FindFirstIconInDLL() already achieves this goal correctly, albeit inefficiently because of the redundant lookup ...and other issues.

"The code above [...] is pretty inefficient" - That's a poor guess, and it is meaningless, too. This is the way to discover a resource when you do not know its name (unless you're prepared to write a PE image parser for the resource section).

@IInspectable: If EnumResourceNames() + FindResource() is the best way to achieve that goal without writing a PE image parser, then this is the answer I was looking for.

If you want to mimic the Shell, you should use the function I linked, but it seems you're after something else. Also you mention a Windows 7 issue in your other question, I don't reproduce it https://i.imgur.com/ZY1Z9sd.png maybe a bug that was fixed

@SimonMourier: Your icon display is different because you do not have a drop shadow enabled in your theme (it's called an "adornment" by MS).  Also, I have already tried IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage() and it does NOT give me full control over what RT_ICON resource is returned. Try it with the enclosed 256.exe file, which has 249 embedded RT_ICON resources, and notice that it does not return the RT_ICON dimensions that you ask for. See the source at: https://ploxis.com/4Simon

That's exactly why I said you're not after what the shell does, because the shell uses a limited set of icon sizes and doesn't have any use for a 255x255 icon if there's a 256x256 one.

Different icon sizes refer to different RT_ICON resources.  In this question I am only after the RT_GROUP_ICON resource, which is not the same.  Anyway, if you compile the source from https://ploxis.com/4Simon and execute File2ShellIcon.exe 64 256.exe you will see that IShellItemImageFactory::GetImage() does not choose the 64x64px RT_ICON resource from the 256.exe.

Again, that's what I said, by default the Shell doesn't use 64x64. Only 16, 32, 48 and 256 sizes.

you can of course manuall walk by PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY and PIMAGE_RESOURCE_DATA_ENTRY for find best icon. t will be bit "efficient" compare EnumResourceNames() + FindResource() but require much more code

@SimonMourier:  Actually the Shell multiplies these icon sizes by the DPI Scaling Factor, which results in a myriad of possible icon sizes ( depending on the setting in the Control Panel's item named "Make text and other items larger or smaller" and in the dialog titled: "Window Color and Appearance/Icon ...Size" ).  Do you want me to upload an Icon Handler shell extension with OutputDebugString() in the IExtractIcon::Extract() method to prove that ?

@RbMm: Isn't parsing the PE Header the only option to those who want to use theIInitializeWithStream::Initialize() in an Icon Handler shell extension?

@GeorgeRobinson possible use code like this if want. however here relative many code. i use CreateIconFromResourceEx finally

"FindResource() finds the first resource by its identifier again - despite it having been located by EnumResourceNames() already." EnumResourceNames never found the resource. It found the resource name. Just like how FindFirstFile doesn't find the file. It just finds file names. You still have to open the file.


Is there a simpler [...] method?

No. The resource API is based on names (or numeric IDs). There is no interface taking an ordinal; resources can be accessed by name only. Translating an index into a name requires enumeration, discarding the first n - 1 items.
While it seems reasonable that EnumResourceNamesW maintains the storage order of resources, this aspect isn't specified. I don't know how (or if) User Interface Language Management affects the order.

Is there a [...] more efficient method?

The "simple" solution seems wasteful: Enumeration has (internally) already navigated to the resource of interest, but throws it away only for us to re-discover it in a subsequent call to FindResourceW. This cannot be avoided via the public API (as explained above).
A more efficient alternative requires sidestepping the API and manually navigating the PE image. I will strongly advise against doing this, but if it is something you want to explore, here is a rough outline of the steps involved:

Get the module's load address.
Skip over the DOS header to the PE header; read and store NumberOfSections and SizeOfOptionalHeader.
Skip to the optional header and read its Magic number to determine whether this is a PE or PE+ image.
Navigate to the Windows-specific fields and read the NumberOfRvaAndSizes value.
Index into the data directories to read the offset and size of the resource table.
Read the resource section table header.
Parse the .rsrc section.

That's a lot of work, and none of it is trivial. At a minimum, all pointers must be verified to fall into the designated area(s) of memory before dereferencing them.
